# ¿Cómo puedo leer una porción de un txt en python y hacerle un formato?

Tags: python, txt

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final quiero que se ordenen los datos de una manera que quede de esta forma ip:port y se separen por filas hacía abajo

Comment: Y que has intentado?

Comment: Mínimo ¿puedes escribir las ip para copiar y pegarlas?

Comment: Si te da flojera utiliza https://www.i2ocr.com/ para extraer el texto de las imágenes

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
with open("f.txt", "r" ) as f:
    for x in f.readlines():
        port,ip = x.split()
        print("{}:{}".format(ip, port ) , )
        # redireccionar a archivo version corta
        # print("{}:{}".format(ip, port ),file=open("ips.txt","a+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

No tiene mucha ciencia. Aquí te dejo lo que pides. Quizá a alguien más le pueda ayudar.

```
archivo=open(r'C:\Users\tu_usuario\Desktop\ip:port.txt', 'w')

with open(r'C:\Users\tu_usuario\Desktop\ip_puertos_desordenados.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f.readlines():
        ip=line.rstrip("\n")[6:]
        puertos = line.rstrip("\n")[:5]
        archivo.write(f'{ip}:{puertos}\n')
archivo.close()
```

Comment: una forma más fácil `ip, puerto = line.strip().spltit(" ")`

Comment: Es lo mismo :P, no te voy a mentir, pensé en hacerlo así, pero lo dejo más digerible para la persona que ha abierto esta pregunta

Comment: Pues si pero puede fallar si el puerto tiene más o menos dígitos. O si hay más o menos espacios que separan esos 2 datos

Comment: Es verdad, pero asumiendo que todos los puertos tienen una longitud de 5 números y solo tienen un espacio, se puede utilizar esa forma, en caso contrario, lo mejor es utilizar `line.strip().spltit(" ")`

Comment: Y por que @Christian no publica su propia respuesta o editan esta agregando la alternativa?

Comment: Además, si colocas `for line in f` en lugar de `for line in f.readlines()` te vas a evitar cargar el archivo entero en memoria.

Comment: @DanteS. Ya esta la respuesta de Bryro, por eso no puse la mía. En cuanto a editar esta la puede hacer Ulises, no lo hago yo por que no es absolutamente necesario